# sendAsynchronousRequest method will excute block code before block outside code

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

when i use `sendAsynchronousRequest` method at that time this method inner block will execute after outside code will execute?

```
__block NSDictionary *dict;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
    {
        NSInteger httpStatus = [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode];
        NSLog(@"httpStatus inside block:%d",httpStatus);
        if ([data length]>0 && connectionError==nil)
        {
            dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
        }
        else if (connectionError)
        {
            UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[connectionError localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alt show];
        }
    }];

return dict;//it will return null because it will run before execute inner block of sendAsynchronousRequest
```

Comment: Add a completion block to return your dictionary contents

Comment: Yes. That's what makes the method asynchronous. The "completionHandler" will not be called until the request is complete. This seems like an incomplete question, perhaps you can clarify what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous request always run in the network thread.
Your [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] means that the block-callback will schedule in mainQueue.
If you wanna to wait until the request finished, you can use synchronous request, or use semaphore to block current thread.

See

```
+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error;
```

but attention that this way to request will block current thread. be careful when using this way.

Comment: i can use this method but when i use this method at that time `UIActivityIndicatorView` will not working

Comment: What do you want to ? block current thread or run in a background thread.

Comment: `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:) withObject:nil];` i can user this but error will occur

Answer (score 0):

You should use block method

First define a block

```
       typedef void (^OnComplate) (NSDictionary * dict);
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [self getDataWithBlokc:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
        NSLog(@"%@",dict);
    }];
}
```

Use the following method

```
-(void)getDataWithBlokc:(OnComplate)block{
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         NSInteger httpStatus = [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode];
         NSLog(@"httpStatus inside block:%d",httpStatus);
         if ([data length]>0 && connectionError==nil)
         {
            NSDictionary* dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

             block(dict);
         }
         else if (connectionError)
         {
             UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[connectionError localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
             [alt show];
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: where call this method?

Comment: where you want to get data.

Comment: you can return anything with this (NSDictionary * dict)

Comment: `__block NSDictionary *dataUser;
    [self getDataWithBlokc:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
        dataUser=dict;
    } :request];`
    
    return dataUser;

Comment: but `dataUser` will null.